# Html, Body 100% Height and dynamic width for content

Tags: html, css

I know that there are Questions here that covers parts of my Question but I can´t put them together to make my layout work.

So basically I want a two Column Layout with a fixed Sidebar and dynamic Content fill up the remaining space.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>Nav 1</li>
            <li>Nav 2</li>
            <li>Nav 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#content {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 200px;*/
}

#navbar{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

With this CSS I have the Problem that my content isn´t taking up the remaining Space, and if I remove the float I get a vertical scrollbar because there´s a margin on top!

Any suggestions how I can achieve 100% Height without scrollbar (no overflow hidden because that doesn´t remove the margin on top) and dynamic content width?

thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Ironically it works with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRNsN/)

Comment: @Itay uh, a violin? What about a URL?

Comment: you want your div#content have a dynamic width ?

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that gives you 100% height for both content and the navbar:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92c6M/

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>Nav 1</li>
        <li>Nav 2</li>
        <li>Nav 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#content {
    height:100%;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #DDF;
}

#navbar{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #CEC;
}
```

Comment: wow this is a really nice solution, didn´t know about the calc! Does this work with all browsers e.g. IE7 or even 6?

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/gXubX/2/

```
.container { 
    width: 100%;
    background: fuchsia;
}

.left {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: purple;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

And a clearfix applied to the container.

Comment: I´ve tried your suggestion but I have still a margin on top and now also on the bottom http://jsfiddle.net/tqEfS/1/

Comment: thanks but that doesn´t fix my problem with the 100% height and the vertical scrollbar that I´m getting...look at the bottom of the page this should be a straight line http://jsfiddle.net/tqEfS/2/

Comment: Sorry I don´t get it...I want the content and the sidebar to be 100% height! This is not the case in your fiddle, min-height: 300px;

Comment: If I set the overflow to hidden it work´s so I will accept your answer ;-) and thanks for your help

Comment: I didn't get you need the container with 100% height, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/gXubX/4/

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
  #wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 positon: relative;
 }

 #navbar {
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
background-color: red;
z-index: 2;
 }

  #content-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
z-index: 1;
 }

  #content {
left: 200px;
margin-left: 200px;
background-color: green;
z-index: 3;
color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navbar"></div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        asdfasfdasdfasdg asdga sdgasdg asdgasdgasdgasdg
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don´t want the navbar to be dynamic it should have a fixed width

Comment: close but that leads to an horizontal scrollbar :-/